# Is it possible to let AWS assign CIDR block for you based on block size and VPC CIDR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, aws-cloudformation, subnet, vpc

When I create an AWS Cloudformation stack I declare in the `Resources` field:

```
Resources:

  SubnetPublic:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref CidrBlockPublic
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True

      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${DomainName}-public"
```

But having statically declared `CidrBlockPublic` is not very convenient and human-error prone. Is the an approach where AWS could calculate the right CIDR block within the VPC CIDR? For example:

I would have VPC CIDR as 10.0.0.0/16 and I wish to have subnet CIDR size of 8. So when I create a subnet inside VPC, the AWS would take that size into account and create 8-host sized network (for example, 10.0.2.0/29 or 10.0.1.100/29 etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fn::Cidr](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-cidr.html) to autogenerate CIDR ranges. There is nothing else, unless you implement your own solution in the form of [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).